# Выделение запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Возник спор. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли в этом предложении выделять запятыми "специально для вас"?

Мы рады каждому новому абоненту и, специально для вас, разработали акцию«Welcome bonus»!

Answer (score 1):

По правилам, здесь запятые не нужны, но они возможны в качестве интонационных авторских знаков как обособленное обстоятельство

Answer (score 1):

1. При обособлении вы выделяете оборот, подчеркивая его значимость. Без обособления смысловым центром становится  "разработали акцию «Welcome bonus".  Так что оба варианта допустимы, все зависит от смысла.
2. Однако читается фраза не лучшим образом в обоих вариантах - нет в ней гладкости и равновесия частей, язык как бы спотыкается при чтении.
3. Лучше написать:Мы рады каждому новому абоненту и разработали акцию «Welcome bonus» специально для вас.Смысловым центром здесь является  "специально для вас".Может быть, абонентам это будет приятно (смайлик).